# Windows Phone 8 WebBrowser does not run javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to build a WebBrowser application that targets Windows Phone 8 SDK, I had another one for WP8.1 and WebView and now i want to support earlier OS version. The thing is, the capability of executing javascript (either internal script or injected script) after WebBrowser makes a post request is impossible.

I tried posting data using 2 methods:

- send a HttpWebRequest request and save result into a local html file and then tell the WebBrowser to navigate to.
- simply just call Navigate(uri, data, headers) on WebBrowser to let it post data

Both 2 methods failed to execute javascript after the result had been returned including script inside < script > tag in html and script I injected on LoadCompleted event. The javascript code is simple enough, I tested it thoroughly and made it works with WP8.1 version so it should be no error in my script (by the way, there is no good way to debug js in WP8 like WP8.1 even in Visual Studio 2013 - that sucks).

Anyone has any clue what is going with this old WebBrowser control or any workaround that I can go for this case?

Comment: You probably want to try [Chromium Embedded](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) rather than a standard WebBrowser and it will run JavaScript

Comment: i did some googling and it seems that chromium embedded is not available  for windows phone

Answer (score 1):

The [WebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled(v=vs.105).aspx) Property defaults to false. Set it to true if you know that the script in your page is safe and want to run it.

Comment: isScriptEnabled is set to true, that's not the problem